# Select DIV ID based on its class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select and use a DIV's ID but I don't know the name of it so I want to search for its class which I know.  How would I do that?  I can use either plain JS or jQuery, doesn't matter.

I want to be able to get the whole ID based purely on its `HA` class.  A sample div looks like

```
<div class="HA" id="k2348382383838382133">
```

The only way I have been able to get it to work is if I use a regular expression with the first few characters of the ID that I know are not changing (for now) but may in the future so I don't want to risk it.

```
var selectDivID = $('div[id^="k23"]');
```

Comment: How do you select a specific DIV? Following user interaction or what?

Comment: Nope, as soon as the page loads, it needs to find any and all HA class DIVs and get their ID.  Sorry for not being more clearer.

Comment: That's ok then but what do you want to do with the IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the class, why don’t you just select the element natively using [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)?

```
var id = document.getElementsByClassName('HA').item(0).id;
```

Of course, you can also iterate the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) if there’s more items (and not `null`).

If you have to assert it’s a `div`, and if you want to get them all, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead:

```
var IDs = [];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.HA'),
                             function(item){ IDs.push(item.id) });
console.log(IDs);
```

Comment: Ya, i think the question is missing some context to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you dakab, ultimately this was the way to go and it works great for me!

Answer (score 4):

Use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.HA').each(function(){
    var selectDivID = $(this).attr('id'); // or this.id
});
```

```js
$('.HA').each(function() {
  var selectDivID = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(selectDivID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="HA" id="k2348382383838382133"></div>
<div class="HA" id="k2344444444444444444"></div>
<div class="HA" id="k234543544545454454"></div>
<div class="HA" id="k2346787878778787878"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks AmmarCSE!  How would this work in a FOR loop with multiple HA DIVs?

Comment: @SS113, the `$('.HA').each(`  is functioning like a for loop by iterating over each `.HA` element.

Answer (score 2):

If there's only one `div` with that class, you can simply do this:

```js
var selectDivID = $('div.HA')[0].id;
console.log(selectDivID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="HA" id="k2348382383838382133">
```